# After system repair, snapd service is not running/fails to restart

Tags: snap, services, 20.10

I have kubuntu 20.10 that was moved from a bad hard disk to a new one. After I managed to get the system running, I have the following problem: any reference to snap (eg. snap refresh) results in the following error:

> error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused

As suggested in various other places, I tried to restart snap:
`systemctl restart snapd`

Which did not work:

> Job for snapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status snapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

`systemctl status snapd`

> systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
> systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
> systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
> systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
> systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.

`journalctl -xe`

> Journal file /var/log/journal/01b4740d96764e08a9d72db26b6152ca/system@0005b814dc04bedd-c0e64a0174849be3.journal~ is truncated, ignoring file.
> A start job for unit snapd.service has finished with a failure.

> The job identifier is 10214 and the job result is failed.
> snapd.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
> Subject: Unit failed
> Defined-By: systemd
> Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> The unit snapd.socket has entered the 'failed' state with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.  snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure=
> dependencies.
> systemd[1]: Starting Failure handling of the snapd
> snap...  Subject: A start job for unit snapd.failure.service has begun
> execution  Defined-By: systemd  Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
> A start job for unit snapd.failure.service has begun execution.    The
> job identifier is 10359.  snapd.failure.service: Succeeded.  Subject:
> Unit succeeded  Defined-By: systemd  Support:
> http://www.ubuntu.com/support    The unit snapd.failure.service has
> successfully entered the 'dead' state.  Finished Failure handling of
> the snapd snap.  Subject: A start job for unit snapd.failure.service
> has finished successfully  Defined-By: systemd  Support:
> http://www.ubuntu.com/support    A start job for unit
> snapd.failure.service has finished successfully.    The job identifier
> is 10359.

Any ideas how to get it fixed?

**Additional info:**

The /var partition was recovered from a faulty drive with ddrescue, had errors fixed by e2fsck after recovery.

Comment: @bardia rajabi, no VPN here, the problem was caused by snap internal data corruption caused by hard disk damage. I was asking is there a way to repair a snap without full reinstall.

Comment: A workaround script can be found in:
https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script

Answer (score 7):

A brute force fix:

```
sudo apt purge snapd
sudo apt install snapd
```

Followed by manual re-installation of all snaps.

If anyone can suggest a better fix, you are welcome.

Comment: It works fine but it removes the span and the packages installed via snap.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run `/usr/lib/snapd/snapd` by hand and see what happens.

In my case I mounted snaps directory to `/var/snapd` instead of `/var/lib/snapd` and got error:

```
cannot run daemon: fatal: directory "/var/lib/snapd" must be present
```